# Find lowest array from attr and do action with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, attr

```
<li data-meter='2231'>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/">
</li>


<li data-meter='0'>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/000">
</li>

<li data-meter='622'>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/000">
</li>
```

How can i use `$("li").attr('data-meter');` and find lowest to do some action ?

http://jsfiddle.net/4Pmzh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [min on Array from John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/)

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Function to get the Min value in Array
    Array.min = function( array ){
       return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
    };

    var meter= $('li').map(function() {
        return $(this).data('meter');
    }).get();

    // alert the minimum value
    alert("Min meter: " + Array.min(meter));
    // or get the jQuery object
    $('li[data-meter="'+Array.min(meter)+'"]')
});
```

[Docs for .data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Pmzh/3/)

Comment: So thanks, but how can i get this selector and do action like .css() ?

Comment: Check out the example http://jsfiddle.net/4Pmzh/3/ and it updates the color of the `li` - just to show its working (note i changed the meter values !!!)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code;

```
var lis = $("li");
var lowest = null;
lis.each(function(){
    var dm = parseInt($(this).attr("data-meter"));
    if(lowest == null || lowest>dm){
        lowest = dm;
    }
});
consoloe.log(lowest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not? it's one way of achieving what you want to do. Remember to use parseInt() to transfomr the attribute in an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .val() method to get the value of each matched element, and then find the highest value by storing each li's attributes in an array. Then through a for each loop, you can pull out the highest value in the array. Now that you have the highest data value of the li's, you can find it's corresponding matched element.

```
if($('li').attr('data-meter')==stringHighestValue)){
    //execute
}
```